# Spring webflux with multiple sequential API call and convert to flux object without subscribe and block

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am working on spring reactive and need to call multiple calls sequentially to other REST API using webclient. The issue is I am able to call multiple calls to other Rest API but response am not able to read without subscribe or block. I can't use subscribe or block due to non reactive programming. Is there any way, i can merge while reading the response and send it as flux.
Below is the piece of code where I am stuck.

```
private Flux<SeasonsDto> getSeasonsInfo(List<HuntsSeasonsMapping> l2, String seasonsUrl) {
for (HuntsSeasonsMapping s : l2)
        {
            List<SeasonsJsonDto> list = huntsSeasonsProcessor.appendSeaosonToJson(s.getSeasonsRef());
for (SeasonsJsonDto sjdto:list)
            {
 Mono<SeasonsDto> mono =new  SeasonsAdapter("http://localhost:8087/").callToSeasonsAPI(sjdto.getSeasonsRef());
    //Not able to read stream without subscribe an return as Flux object
}

 public Mono<SeasonsDto> callToSeasonsAPI(Long long1) {
         LOGGER.debug("Seasons API call");
        
          return this.webClient.get().uri("hunts/seasonsInfo/"
          +long1).header("X-GoHunt-LoggedIn-User",
          "a4d4b427-c716-458b-9bb5-9917b6aa30ff").retrieve().bodyToMono(SeasonsDto.class);
         
}
```

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured how to do this. I have completely rewrite the code and change in reactive. It means all the for loop has been removed. Below is the code for the same and may be help for others.

```
public Flux<SeasonsDto> getAllSeasonDetails(String uuid) {

    return hunterRepository.findByUuidAndIsPrimaryAndDeleted(uuid, true, false).next().flatMapMany(h1 -> {
        return huntsMappingRepository.findByHunterIdAndDeleted(h1.getId(), false).flatMap(k -> {
            return huntsMappingRepository.findByHuntReferrenceIdAndDeleted(k.getHuntReferrenceId(), false)
                    .flatMap(l2 -> {
                        return huntsSeasonsProcessor.appendSeaosonToJsonFlux(l2.getSeasonsDtl()).flatMap(fs -> {
                            return seasonsAdapter.callSeasonsAPI(fs.getSeasonsRef(), h1.getId(), uuid).map(k->{
                                return k;
                            });
                        });
                    });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the reactive streams using operators such as `map`, `flatMap` and `concatMap`.

```
private Flux<SeasonsDto> getSeasonsInfo(List<HuntsSeasonsMapping> l2, String seasonsUrl) {
   List<Mono<SeasonsDto>> monos = new ArrayList<>();
   for (HuntsSeasonsMapping s : l2) {
   
      List<SeasonsJsonDto> list = huntsSeasonsProcessor.appendSeaosonToJson(s.getSeasonsRef());
      for (SeasonsJsonDto sjdto:list) {
         Mono<SeasonsDto> mono =new  SeasonsAdapter("http://localhost:8087/").callToSeasonsAPI(sjdto.getSeasonsRef()); 
         //Not able to read stream without subscribe an return as Flux object
         monos.add(mono);
      }
    }
  return Flux.fromIterable(monos).concatMap(mono -> mono);
}
```

This can further be improved using the steam API, which I suggest you look into, but I didn't want to change too much of your existing code.

Comment: Hi Adnan, thanks for your reply, but even the call is happening through webclient doesn't give me data due to reactive and backward programming nature Can you tell me how can we do it via streams . I belive webclient needs to consume inside for loop.